# filter dates format values in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
    colA                      ColB
0   2020-11-30 00:00:00       546
1   Vendor account statement  yrt22
2   :doflat:                  ttys7
3   2020-1-30 00:00:00        970
```

I want to filter 'colA' dates only (any date) other then dates not required. Required dataframe is as below.

```
    colA                      ColB
0   2020-11-30 00:00:00       546
1   2020-1-30 00:00:00        970
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need datetimes in output replace non datetimes no misisng values and rmeove rows:

```
df['colA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colA'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['colA'])
```

If need original values test for values possible converted, so here not missing values:

```
df = df[pd.to_datetime(df['colA'], errors='coerce').notna()]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use:

```py
df['colA'].str.contains('^\d+-\d+-\d+ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$')
```

The regex pattern `^\d+-\d+-\d+ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$` should match the datetime/timestamp values shown which you want to retain, see the demo:

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df[[type(i)==pd.Timestamp for i in df['colA']]]
```

Comment: We're just creating a Boolean list by comparing each element type with timestamp using list comprehension . And we're finally filtering the df only for True outcomes.